# Where is web framework webwork?

Tags: java, frameworks, webwork

I'm interested in using webwork 2, after great experience on struts 1.2 on previous project.

But after I checked on [webwork](http://www.opensymphony.com/webwork/), the latest release is 2007 and the few documentation tutorial status "is in progress".
Anybody know is it still being developed or released periodically?

Comment: google timeline: http://www.google.com/search?q=webwork+framework&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=tl:1&source=lnt&ei=E6wBTL72MtKp_AaimYjjDg&sa=X&oi=tool&resnum=3&ct=tlink&ved=0CBwQpwU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebWork 2 is taken over by Apache in favor of Struts 2. Here's an extract of relevance from the [Struts homepage](http://struts.apache.org/):

> Struts 2 was originally known as [WebWork 2](http://www.opensymphony.com/webwork). After working independently for several years, the WebWork and Struts communities [joined forces](http://struts.apache.org/announce-2005.html#a20051214.3)  to create Struts 2. The 2.x framework is the best choice for teams who value elegant solutions to difficult problems.

Comment: Hi balusc, so in conclusion webwork 2.2.7 (latest version since 2007) equals struts 2 (who had the latest release Nov 2009) ???

is it right?